# Negative event times encountered; not permitted for Cox family

Tags: r, glmnet, cox-regression

I am running a coxph model using *glmnet*. The following is the code that I am using:

```
data <- read.csv("CSM Tiers by Org.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, na.strings = "?")
x <- model.matrix(~ data$CSM + data$Exclude +  data$Queue)
y <- data$Time
status <- data$Event
glmnet(x,Surv(y,status), family = "cox")
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
Error in coxnet(x, is.sparse, ix, jx, y, weights, offset, alpha, nobs,  : 
negative event times encountered;  not permitted for Cox family
```

But I dont see any negative event times in my data.

```
> sum(y<0)
[1] 0
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Without out data to make this error [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), it will be very difficult to help you.

Comment: @MrFlick:   I am trying to upload the data...but its too big of a file.

Comment: We don't need your exact input file. See the tips in the link I provided for creating a representative input data set. It just has to be enough to trigger the exact same error you are getting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check if sum(y<=0). The code in the function says it will return that error if y's equal 0 as well.

Code is here, error you're referencing is on line 5:
https://github.com/jeffwong/glmnet/blob/master/R/coxnet.R

Comment: Thanks @Branden Murray! I found that the data set indeed had some 0's. The model ran when the 0s are removed